# Storing Key value pair in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In Java , i can use property file as shown below to store the elements ID and implement as the same

```
CountryName=USA

driver.findElement(By.name(prop.getProperty("CountryName"))).click();
```

Is there any such way in c# where i can store the key value pairand retrieve the same while execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> intMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
intMap.Add("One", 1);
intMap.Add("Two", 2);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValue in intMap) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
}
```

Or Simply use this code:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> NAME_HERE = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("defaultkey", "defaultvalue");
```

Comment: Thats a good idea! , what if I want to store lots of key value pair's almost for like 100 of element id's. Is there in way like  , storing all this in a separate static class and then use those element's id.?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use a Dictionary suggested by SandySands, you can locate the value by the key

```
var countries = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  {"USA", "id_1"},
  {"UK", "id_2"},
};

// locate the value by key: countries[key]
driver.findElement(countries["USA"]).click()
```

If the type of id is just int, I would recommend to use Enum instead.

```
Public Enum Country
{
  USA = 1,
  UK = 2,
}

driver.findElement(((int)CountryCountry.USA).ToString()).click()
```

Comment: what if i want to locate an element with xpath and then the second element with its classname , can you please suggest some idea. I need to store lot many elements id , just thinking how to do that and use it.

Comment: Just parse the static XML file into XElement class and initial the Dictionary in run time. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can directly provide details by **providing KEY as element** as shown

```
Dictionary<string, string> DE = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 DE.Add("ID1", "34 Employees, 50 Computers");
 DE.Add("ID2", "100 Employees, 67 Computers");
 string details = DE["ID1"]; // Key "ID1" shall give the detals as "34 Employees, 50 Computers"
```

Comment: driver.findelement(By.name("Login")).sendkeys("xyz") <-- In this line of code  , how can i store the value "Login" to a key and implement it. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string> DE = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 DE.Add("Login", "xyz");
 DE.Add("Login1", "abc");   string details = DE["Login"];`

Comment: you can add "Login" as a key,the dictionary is a combination of Key and a Value, where the first element is a key and second a value, as, Dictionary<Key,Value> hence you can find results as explained in the code.